# werkzeug generate_password_hash, is there any point?

Tags: python, werkzeug

I'm building a python app that uses [werkzeug's hashing functions](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/utils/#module-werkzeug.security). An example `User` model:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    # Custom property getter
    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')

    # Custom property setter
    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

I see that now the `password` is stored as a hash in the database and any attacker who sees the hash won't know what the password is without decrypting it. However isn't werkzeug's hashing function a fairly obvious choice for a lot of apps? Could the attacker just use the [`check_password_hash`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/utils/#werkzeug.security.check_password_hash) function and decrypt the password?

Comment: I think you'll find `check_password_hash` **doesn't** decrypt the password; I'd imagine it hashes the supplied password and compares it to the stored hash (i.e. it's roughly going to be `return self.password_hash == generate_password_hash(password)`). The whole point of hashing (ideally with salting) is that it's **not reversible**; it's hashing, not encrypting.

Comment: Indeed you can see the [description in the docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/utils/#werkzeug.security.check_password_hash) and [the code on GitHub](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/security.py#L234).

Comment: For more information on the subject, see [security.se]: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33860/72084

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why would `check_password_hash` work within my app for a particular hash but that same hash won't decrypt in someone else's app? Is there a key that is particular to the app that ensures it only works on this particular app?

Comment: It would work exactly the same. That's why you salt before hashing, otherwise someone could just run the hash algorithm on all possible passwords and do a reverse lookup. The algorithm is one-way, it cannot be run backwards, **that is the point**. Please read up on the basics, that will answer most of your questions.

Comment: I completely missed the point! If they steal the hash from the database that's all they have. The `check_password_hash` function still needs a valid password for it to return true which they don't have. Man I'm stupid today. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KexAri ... you are not stupid but you are more like UN-HASHABLE  :D :D :D

Comment: Don't worry; it's not stupid, you just didn't have all of the info. The attackers can use the function to test passwords against the hash, but that's why we suggest people use long, uncommon ones; to push up the time needed for a successful attack and dissuade most attackers.

Comment: The random salt sprinkling also ensures that if they do crack one hash and find the password is `password` they can't simply search the db table for users with the same hash and infer they also has the password: `password`. That right?

Comment: Note that the other thing that `passwords_hash` does is take a substantial amount of computational time, generally around 100ms. The main reason for the salt is to insure that two identical passwords will not produce the same hash value and prevent rainbow (pre-calculated) tables.

Comment: @KexAri precisely; as each password has separate salt, it must be cracked separately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essentially `password_hash` uses a one-way function to create a hash that is not reversible. Additionally it adds information to the hash such as the hash algorithm, salt value, iteration count and of course the hash value, this is what is stored. `password_verify` takes the password and the additional information in the result of `password_hash` to again create the hash and compares the hash values.

Additionally and importantly `password_hash` iterates over the hash function to make the process take longer, a good value is 100ms. Thus the best an attacker can do it try passwords to find one that matches and each attempt takes a substantial amount of time. Of course faster computational systems can reduce the ~100ms but it is still costly.

Comment: Why could this not be reversed on someone else's  system? does the hashing function use a system specific secret key?

Comment: Cryptographic hashes are not reversible, that is by design. Among other things data is intentionally lost in the process. It is like hamburger, the steer can not be re-created from the hamburger.

Comment: @KexAri you can't unhash the potato!